# js how to convert date has includes japanese to format en-gb

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

```js
var date = new Date("2016年5月");

date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB');
```

example : **"2016年5月" => "2016-05"**

Comment: extra credits for "28年5月" => "2016-05" ?